# умный фильтр битрикса не выводит товары

Tags: php, битрикс

Фильтр у меня такой.

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.smart.filter", 
    "uni_catalog_smart_filter", 
    array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "1c_catalog", /*Тип инфоблока*/
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "1",/**/
        "SECTION_ID" => "2",
        "SECTION_CODE" => "oils",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arFilter",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
        "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "vertical",
        "DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "Y",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "SAVE_IN_SESSION" => "N",
        "INSTANT_RELOAD" => "Y",
        "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => "arrPager",
        "PRICE_CODE" => array(
            0 => "BASE",
        ),
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "Y",
        "XML_EXPORT" => "N",
        "SECTION_TITLE" => "-",
        "SECTION_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "POPUP_POSITION" => "bottom",

        "SECTION_CODE_PATH" => "",
        "SMART_FILTER_PATH" => $_REQUEST["SMART_FILTER_PATH"],
        "CURRENCY_ID" => "RUB"
    ),
    false
);?>
```

Добавление ниже этого компонента bitrix:catalog.smart.filter компонента catalog_section не привел ни к какому результату. 
компонент такой

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:catalog.section", "unimann_catalog_section", array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "1c_catalog",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "1",
        "SECTION_ID" => "",
        "SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => $field,
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => $order,
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arFilter",
        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
        "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "Y",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
        "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "10000",
        "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "1",
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "BREND",
            1 => "CML2_ARTICLE",
            2 => "DNEY_DOSTAVKI",
            3 => "",
        ),
        "OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "ID",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "CML2_LINK",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => $field,
        "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" => $order,
        "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
        "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
        "OFFERS_LIMIT" => "30",
        "SECTION_URL" => "",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "",
        "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/cart/",
        "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
        "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
        "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "quantity",
        "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
        "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_COMPARE" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "PRICE_CODE" => array(

            1=>"ZAKUPOCHNYEAVTOMEDON_M_OOO",
            2=>"ZAKUPOCHNYESHATE_M_PLYUS_OOO",
            3=>"ZAKUPOCHNYEAVTOTSENTR_ZLATA_OOO",
        ),
        "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
        "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
        "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
        "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array(
        ),
        "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
        "OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES" => array(
        ),

        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => ""
        ),
        false
    );


?>
```

что-то не хватает? Сейчас выводит все товары раздела масла. Но. когда выбираешь нужный  товар по фильтру, фильтр сбрасывается на все товары. И товары все выводятся.  А сам товар по фильтру не выводится. Почему так?

Comment: `"FILTER_NAME" => "arFilter",`, `"FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",` Определитесь там какой у вас все-таки фильтр.

Comment: значения поля `FILTER_NAME` у компонента умного фильтра и компонента каталога должны совпадать, а у Вас они разные. вот он и не работает

Comment: Я поставила один filter_name.... все равно не получается. Его нужно задавать отдельно? например, $arFilter = array("=PROPERTY_INDEKS"=>$artid,"=PROPERTY_BREND"=>$brand);
 $arFilter = array(
            array(
                 "LOGIC" => "OR",
                 $arFilter
                )
            );
Не получается.... у меня выводит все  товары, которые есть в разделе. По фильтру так не выбирается.

Comment: попробуйте в настройках фильтра убрать явное определиние id инфоблока и раздела, а также символьного кода. Если хотите ограничить вывод товаров разделом, то делайте это в компоненте каталога через такие же настройки.

Comment: Измените название фильтра `"FILTER_NAME" => "arFilter"`, к примеру на `"FILTER_NAME" => "arMySuperFilter"`. Т.к. в комоненте (и не только в `bitrix:catalog.section`) уже используется переменная $arFilter, а вы делаете ее глобальной. Соответственно ни к чему хорошему это не приводит.